# C# LinkedResource using base64 string

Tags: c#, email, base64

How can I put this ==>
`url('data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB')` into `new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource()`

to send mail form C#, using background css style with base64 string, not file url.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I wondered this myself and got to this post. I solved it and figured i would share the my solution.

```
var imageData = Convert.FromBase64String("/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB");

var contentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var linkedResource = new LinkedResource(new MemoryStream(imageData), "image/jpeg");
linkedResource.ContentId = contentId;
linkedResource.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;

var body = string.Format("<img src=\"cid:{0}\" />", contentId);
var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, "text/html");
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(linkedResource);
```

Comment: How is this response not upvoted 100 times? Thank you! Works great!

Comment: @Rocky except that the base64 isnt valid. heres one that work http://jsfiddle.net/casiano/xadvz/