# What's the difference between AlternateView and Attachments in MailMessage?

Tags: c#, email, mailmessage

I have found some sources out there to attach an a base64 as an image and I found some using [AlternateView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24265027/7339324) and others using attachments. I used the AlternateView and I found that it still puts the image as an attachment but loads the content in the body of the MailMessage. I feel that there is a gap in my understanding because no one has explained their code. Also, I read on [msdocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> Gets the attachment collection used to store alternate forms of the message body

Can anyone please explain the difference between the MailMessage.AlternateViews and MailMessage.Attachments?

Comment: Alternate views let you specify an html message and a (for example) plain text message for mail clients that can't display html. Attachments show up as files attached to the message. An AlternateView is a subclass of Attachment.. It represents the (in this case) html part of the message that its attached to the main plain text one. To display an image in your html message but not have it show as an attachment, you created a linked resource with a content ID, you can then use the content ID as the "url" of the image but I *think* you can only do that in the context of an AlternateView

Comment: Can they be used in conjunction with each other? So MailMessage.AlternativeViews.Add(alternativeView) and similarly, MailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment) in the same MailMessage object?

Comment: Yes they can. You'd get a "classic" attachment and then an alternate view in that case. Please note it's Alter**nate**View and not Alter**native**View

Comment: Much appreciated.